Transform envvar style substrings based on their env values
I have strings that are comprised of substrings such as:

${ENV_VAR1}
$(ENV_VAR2)

Where ENV_VAR1 and ENV_VAR2 etc are possibly environment variables.
When they are environment variables, wanting to replace them in the
string with their associated value, and if they're not want the actual
substring to remain.
Example1 Given the following env vars:
ENV_VAR1 = "XYZ"
ENV_VAR2 = "123"

And input string:
"something/${ENV_VAR1}/else|$(ENV_VAR2)"

result:
"something/XYZ/else|123"

Example2 Given the following env vars:
ENV_VAR1 = "XYZ"

And input string:
"something/${ENV_VAR1}/else|$(ENV_VAR2)"

result:
"something/XYZ/else|$(ENV_VAR2)"


So... replace them? You could use std::regex to look for the env-patterns in the string, and then replace them. Or you just do it yourself -- these patters are pretty trivial to parse

Ehh, not clear what you are asking. If you want to replace the strings, then do so. If you do not want to replace the strings, then don't. What's so hard about that and what's the question? You read a string, you do the transformation you want (possibly first identifying and reading environment variables and using their values for substitutions), you write an output string. Not terribly complicated.

I'm going to assume this isn't a simple search and replace problem, so with that the following routine uses getenv to see if there's a match with any registered environment variables, then proceeds to expand/transform the matches to their values registered in the env.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <regex>
#include <string>


std::string expand_env_variables(const std::string& input)
{
    if ((input.find("${") == std::string::npos) && (input.find("$(") == std::string::npos))
    {
        return input;
    }

    constexpr auto pattern = R"(([$]\((\w|[^\)]+)\)|[$]\{(\w|[^\}]+)\}))";
    static const std::regex envvar_regex(pattern);

    std::smatch match;

    std::string result = input;

    while (std::regex_search(result, match, envvar_regex))
    {
        const auto& envvar = match.str(!match.str(2).empty() ? 2 : 3);
        const char* s = std::getenv(envvar.c_str());
        const std::string expanded_var { s ? s : "" };

        result.replace(match[0].first, match[0].second, expanded_var);
    }

    if (input != result)
    {
        printf("expand_env_variables: Input expanded %s ----> %s\n", input.c_str(), result.c_str());
    }

    return result;
}


Note: the usage of the magic numbers 2 and 3 are because the indexes of regex match group, which arise when using conditional regexes patterns.
